# I want to set a max number of rows in MySQL table and Delete

Tags: php, sql

what i actual want that i want to insert data in sql table but i want to limit table with 50 row no more and when i insert new data it delete the old data as new data enter
for example 
there is 50 data already in table i add 10 new data the new data will insert and table show delete 10 rows from beginning.
if new data(rows) 10 and already data in db is 45 row so it delete first 5 rows and add new 5
so i need help and suggestion how to put restriction on table and when i new data came it delete from start row some rows if data exceed 50 rows
thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a free write-my-code service, but we will try to help you fix your code. What have you tried? What are you stuck with? Break the process down into steps, and try and write a SQL statement for each part. Is there a specific bit which puzzles you?

Comment: Look into triggers.

Comment: You can start hiring people by posting something on your local newspaper, but I don't believe people will tell you how to do stuff for free, let alone here. Search for information, do it on your own, and if you get stuck, ask another question that is simple, answerable, specific, and programming related, posting the code that is not working.

Comment: okay sure thanks i would do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why?  You are just making the inserts take longer.

Instead, you can insert new rows and use an auto-incrementing primary key.  Then you can do something like:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.id desc
fetch first 50 rows only;
```

This will get you the most recent 50 rows.  And the query should perform quite well.

What advantages does this have?

- You get to keep all the data, which is quite useful to see what happened in the past.
- Performance is not affected.
- You can change "50" to another number on-the-fly.
- Your inserts are not slowed down by deletes.
- There is no need to deal with triggers and other complexity.

Of course, if your table is going to grow to tens of millions of rows, this might not be the optimal solution (the table itself will start to eat up memory for other purposes).  But for smallish tables, this is a very viable solution.

Comment: your solution is helpful for me on  some table i should apply that becasue they are small but actually i have script that update every 30 second and it take number of data sometime 20 some time 10 so i want to make table short and delete old but i think i should use your query and make another query for delete that check data to limit 50 rows and delete from start that would work may be .

Comment: @David . . . You can always periodically remove all but 50 values from the table.  Even one insert every 30 seconds is only about 3,000 inserts per day, so that is not very much.